# GUI framework to create a Windows app with opacity that can be captured by OBS

Tags: windows, user-interface, frameworks, opacity, obs

The question breaks down into two:

1. Is it even possible to create a Windows app with an opaque (not fully transparent) background that can be overlayed on top of other sources in OBS? Any examples of such apps?
   What I mean is:
   [image]

2. If yes to (1), then what GUI frameworks (preferably C++) can be used to reach this? I know for sure that WinUI and WPF can't do it.
   Dear GUI, Sciter, Cegui?

Comment: In the OBS forum you seem to suggest you achieved it.  Is what you developed available?